# retrieve property values from message broker bar file with java api

Tags: java, mq, messagebroker

I'm trying to read the property values from a bar file created by message broker.

I want to do this via java. The api is here: `http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fbe43410_.htm`

However, I can only figure out how to get the names of the properties NOT THEIR VALUES by using the deployment descriptor. I can see how to override the value that a property has, but once again, not how to retrieve the value. Another words I can see only how to write to the property not read from it. I want to do both! Call me greedy ;)

If I use the command line based utility: `http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Faf03900_.htm`
I can get the property values no problem.

But I want to get them via java if at all possible.

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was misunderstanding how the deployment descriptor worked. I thought that when the java API referred to overridden properties it meant ones that were over ridden in my java code. But it actually meant all the properties that had a value in the bar file.

That being said getting the values is not strait forward. You have to get all the identifiers and then pass them to getOverride();

```
BarFile b = BarFile.loadBarFile("C:\\BarParamTest\\myBar.bar");
DeploymentDescriptor d =  b.getDeploymentDescriptor();

Enumeration<String> properties = d.getPropertyIdentifiers();

while(properties.hasMoreElements())
{
    String p = properties.nextElement();
    System.out.println(p + " = " + d.getOverride(p));
}
```

or use the following to only list properties that have values

```
Enumeration<String> properties = d.getOverriddenPropertyIdentifiers();
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason settings are not written to file, if they are not overriden or not changed.(the reason is the lack of necessity to keep the property's default value:) ) so the way to get the properties is to know their default values. But I would recommend you to use  `com.ibm.mq.jar` library if you're able to connect to broker to read properties using method

```
java.util.Properties MessageFlowProxy.Node.getProperties()
```

from already deployed .bar.